# Java, Mule - Throw different types of exceptions on one Validation component

Tags: java, validation, exception, mule, custom-exceptions

In a flow I've designed, I have a Validation component with a custom validator that references a class, `DataValidator`, implementing the mule [Validator](https://gist.github.com/marianogonzalez/b02b83f778baf1d174ff#file-validator-java) interface. In the `DataValidator`, I validate several properties and would like to throw different kinds of exceptions (possibly custom exceptions, created by me) for each one. Is this possible?

My understanding is that, by specifying the `exceptionClass`, the Validation component will only throw exceptions of that class.

There's the option to use an [ExceptionFactory](https://gist.github.com/marianogonzalez/2e533b2edfd889f2643c#file-exceptionfactory-java) instead of an `exceptionClass`.
Does using it allows throwing several types of exception? If so, how can I use it? I checked [this](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/tech-ramblings/introducing-the-validations-module/) blog 
post, but didn't understand it well enough.

In the case that none of this is possible, is there any way I can get the [ValidationResult](https://gist.github.com/marianogonzalez/69af1dfc71d54e94351a#file-validationresult-java) message in the custom validator component, so that I can use it in the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can throw several types of exceptions. As you mentioned, you'll have to implement the `DataValidator` and `ExceptionFactory` interface and configure your component to use them.

With Studio, choose *"Use Exception Factory Config"* and specify the full class name you want to use. With XML, specify the `exception-factory` you implemented in your `validation-config`. (You can also configure a Spring Bean and reference it):

```
    <validation:config name="Validation_Configuration" doc:name="Validation Configuration">
        <validation:exception-factory class="com.mycomp.validation.MyExceptionFactory"/>
    </validation:config>
```

In your flow configure a`custom-validator` and reference your configuration with exception factory, your validator implementation and the type of exception you want to throw with `exceptionClass`. To be able to throw any kind of Exception, specify `java.lang.Exception` or a class from which the custom exceptions you'll want to use can inherit:

```
<flow name="validation-exceptionFlow">
    ...
    <validation:custom-validator
        config-ref="Validation_Configuration" 
        class="com.mycomp.validation.MyValidator"
        exceptionClass="java.lang.Exception" 
        doc:name="Validation" />
    ...
</flow>
```

Depending on your need you may want to specify `exceptionClass` differently, the idea being that your actual exceptions should extend it.

Yout `ExceptionFactory` implementation is then up to you. You can return whatever exception you want... For example:

```
public class MyExceptionFactory implements ExceptionFactory{

    @Override
    public <T extends Exception> T createException(ValidationResult result, Class<T> exceptionClass, MuleEvent event) {
        return (T) createException(result, exceptionClass.getCanonicalName(), event);
    }

    @Override
    public Exception createException(ValidationResult result, String exceptionClassName, MuleEvent event) {
        //...
        //some logic to identify which kind of exception you want to throw
        //from result and event
        //...
        if(something) {
            return new SomeException("Something happened");
        } else if (somethingElse) {
            return new AnotherException("I am en error...");
        } else {
            return new BananaException("Ook");
        }
    }

}
```

It appears the interface has two methods, one returning a generic and the other a plain `Exception`. Not knowing the specific usage of your `ExceptionFactory` I won't be able to provide much guidance, but be aware that Mule may call any of these methods, and [the doc provides some requirements](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/building-a-custom-validator#customizing-exception-class-and-message):

> The above interface receives the Event that was rejected by the
>   validation and the validator that raised the error. This method is
>   intended to return the exception to be thrown but not to throw it.
>   Implementations of this interface should never throw exceptions. They
>   should also be thread-safe and have a public default constructor. See
>   Also

Comment: Thanks a lot, but meanwhile I decided to switch the custom Validation components to Invoke components and "manually" throw the exceptions I wanted. I've marked your answer as the solution, because the `MyExceptionFactory` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Great thanks. Using a custom Component seems indeed a more suitable solution for your needs!